# Setting up a document in Lyx

Tags: lyx, fontsize, font-encodings

I use Lyx 2.1, document class : report.
I want to set the document as follows:

font: Times New Roman
size: 12 points
space between the title and paragraph : 6 before and after

Comment: Add `\usepackage{times}` to your preamble, but consider that—typographically—these are borderline awful parameters.  What is your use case?  What are you trying to create?

Comment: I want to create a repot, with features that I mention

Comment: @user1936895 First of all, Lyx really comes with a nice tutorial. There is no other way than to read it. The hint of Sean Allred probably is not the best way: In the Documents Menu you'll find the fonts and the drop down menu offers Times Roman. Second: Please get a better nick than that stupid number.

Comment: Ah, if there's a menu option for Times as Keks mentions, then that is probably better to use.  I will note though that you missed the point of my questions.  Are you trying to write a paper that must adhere to strict requirements?  (If it's academic, what level are you?)  What is your *use case*?  *Why* do you want `6pt` separation between paragraphs (`\setlength\parskip{12pt}`)—why is paragraph indentation not enough?  (`\setlength\parindent{0pt}`)  It's considered bad practice to use both, but (unfortunately) it's not an uncommon requirement of schools that don't know better.